# which python interpreter should I use with flask_sqlalchemy lib?

Tags: python, flask

`from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

at this line pycharm is telling me Unresolved reference 'flask_sqlalchemy'. I have found information that some people resolved it by changing python interpreter but which one? I have tried 3.9 and 3.10 and it's not working at all

Comment: Do you have flask SQLAlchemy installed?

Comment: yes i installed it with cmd

Comment: How did you install Flask SQLAchemy?  How are you running your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly recommend using a virtual environment for each Python project instead of using your global Python interpreter. The general solution for your problem can be:

##### 1. Creating virtual env and Install Packages

Using `poetry` for an example:

- Initialize a poetry project on your Python project root

```bash
poetry init
```

- Add your package

> example here is `Flask-SQLAlchemy` in your case

```bash
poetry add Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

- activate a new virtual env in your current terminal

```bash
poetry shell
```

> here it will print **the path** for your new virtual env

##### 2. Add the interpreter in Pycharm

```bash
pycharm -> settings -> project:xxx -> Python Interpreter -> Add Interperter -> select the path:  <YOUR-VENV-PATH>/bin/python3.xx
```

Then your Pycharm IDE will use this interpreter for your current project. Any packages added later to this virtual env can be detected by your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add New **Interpreter**  environment and install requirements.

Comment: I tried to uninstall flask and flask_alchemy and i deleted venv folder and I added new interpreter but it didn't work

Comment: okay, How did you added new interpreter by using pycharm or by manually?